# Can't attach material to imported SVG in python

Tags: python, materials, import

If I import an SVG curve by python, always is working except of assign material. Manually I can assign any material, but by python nothing works. There is part of my code:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Z")
for emboss in embosses:
    emb_name = emboss[:-4]
    loadedSVG = bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath = embossDir + emboss, filter_glob=".svg")
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.tag == False:
            obj.name = emb_name
            obj.tag = True
            x, y, z = obj.dimensions 
            if x >= y:
                needRatio = maxSize / x
            if y > x:
                needRatio = maxSize / y
            bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern = emb_name)
            bpy.data.objects[emb_name].scale = (needRatio, needRatio, needRatio)      

            #two from my attempts, nothing works, material is correct            
            bpy.data.objects[emb_name].materials = [mat]  
            bpy.data.objects[emb_name].setMaterials([mat])  
            #end of not-working code            

            bpy.data.objects[emb_name].rotation_euler = (0, 0, math.radians(90))           
            bpy.data.objects[emb_name].location = (-0.06864 + (maxSize - y * needRatio)/2, 1.18165 + (maxSize - x * needRatio)/2, 0.02419)      
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Only message "AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'materials'" in the system console.

I know that I'm doing some mistake, but I can't find anything three days in code but through the web too. Thanks for correcting my code.

Comment: Please mark Rick Riggs' answer as the solution if it solved your problem or was the most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
        #two from my attempts, nothing works, material is correct            
        bpy.data.objects[emb_name].materials = [mat]  
        bpy.data.objects[emb_name].setMaterials([mat])  
        #end of not-working code
```

Try:

```
        bpy.data.objects[emb_name].active_material = bpy.data.materials['Z']
```

If this still does not work, you may need to look at adding a material slot first.

```
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
```

Comment: Thanx to Rick, it works great.