# How to add a material to the active material slot with python

Tags: python, materials, append

I currently have

```
matName = "Black"

blendfile = addon_dir + "/assets/materials.blend"
selection = "\\Material\\"
material = matName

filepath = blendfile + selection + material
directory = blendfile + selection
filename = material
newMat = bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath=filepath, filename=filename, directory=directory)
mat = bpy.data.materials.get(material)
bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(mat)
```

this appends a material and adds it to the current object. The problem is that it adds a new material slot with the material. How can I make it add the appended material to the active slot?

Comment: Does this post help you [LINK](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48430/cant-attach-material-to-imported-svg-in-python/48433#48433)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of materials that shows in the material properties comes from

```
obj.material_slots
```

The index for the one that is selected in that list is

```
idx = obj.active_material_index
```

using that you assign a material to that slot with

```
obj.material_slots[idx].material = mat
```

Comment: Also equivalent to `obj.active_material = mat`

Comment: This works fine!