# Link objects, but be able to change materials

Tags: linked-data

Is there any way to link an object from another scene, but be able to work with its materials?

For example, I have a model of an airplane which our modeler made.
I want to link the model to a new scene where I will setup lighting and shaders and then render. But if we want to make some modifications in geometry, we could go to the original scene and do it.

Comment: Is your question about linked files or color data on a multi-user mesh?

Comment: What is multi-user mesh?

I have an object (model of an airplane) in model.blend.
I want to link this object to the lighting.blend and be able to modify or create new materials for that object.

Comment: I want to have geometry in file A, materials and lighting in file B. If I want to change geometry, I go to A and change it. In B all changes will be relinked.

Thats what I want

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/multiple-linked-objects-with-unique-materials-group-materials-override. However I could use that only after pressing `L` > *Selected objects*. The object still will remain linked, but you'll be able to change material