# How do I color an entire group of objects at once?

Tags: materials, groups

How do I color selected group (by using materials). I have like 50 objects in one group and I don't want to color them in the same color 50 times.

[image]

Comment: related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/multiple-linked-objects-with-unique-materials-group-materials-override